# SVG linearGradient direction

Tags: svg

I have a simple `linearGradient` inside a circle.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <linearGradient id="ct-svg-gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(65)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
  </linearGradient>

  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#ct-svg-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

As you can see I'm trying to rotate gradient by 65 degrees. At least, that's what [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Types_of_transform_definition) claims it to be. I've tried to set this `rotate` to a bigger number and this will not give an expected result.

I understand that the problem with this one is that `linearGradient` doesn't have it's `transform` origin to the center. I guess, I'd have to use [x1, y1, x2, y2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#LinearGradientElementX1Attribute) attributes for `linearGradient`, with no `gradientTransform` at all. If that's the case, what's the simplest way to get those four values if I have just angle I should rotate gradient to?

I'm interested in implementing such a function, my input is dynamic.

```
function convert(angle_in_degrees) { // or radians, I'll take care of conversion

  // the algorithm I'm interested in

  return {
    x1: ...,
    y1: ...,
    x2: ...,
    y2: ...,
  };
}
```

I'm thankful for any response or suggestion.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <linearGradient id="ct-svg-gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(150)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
  </linearGradient>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#ct-svg-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite as simple as that. in order for your gradient to fill the object from edge to edge, you would need to pass in the element as well and take into account its bounding box.

If you only need to worry about circles, then it would be simpler to apply an axis aligned gradient and rotate the circle.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <linearGradient id="ct-svg-gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
  </linearGradient>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#ct-svg-gradient)" transform="rotate(150,100,100)"/>
</svg>
```

**Update**

Here's a simple JS function that does what you want.  It won't always give the best results, but it should be easy to understand.

```js
function setGradientAngle(elementId, gradientId, angle)
{
  // Convert angle to radians
  angle = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  // Get element bounding box
  var bbox = document.getElementById(elementId).getBBox();
  // Calculate centre of rotation
  var cx = bbox.x + bbox.width/2;
  var cy = bbox.y + bbox.height/2;
  // Minimum radius we need, to guarantee that gradient stretches the full width
  // This calculation could be cleverer. We are just doing worst case here for simplicity.
  var radius = Math.sqrt(bbox.width*bbox.width+bbox.height*bbox.height)/2;
  // Calculate vector from centre to gradient coords
  var rx = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
  var ry = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
  // Update the gradient coords
  var grad = document.getElementById(gradientId);
  grad.setAttribute("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
  grad.setAttribute("x1", cx - rx);
  grad.setAttribute("y1", cy + ry);
  grad.setAttribute("x2", cx + rx);
  grad.setAttribute("y2", cy - ry);
}

setGradientAngle("mypath", "ct-svg-gradient", 150);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <linearGradient id="ct-svg-gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
  </linearGradient>
  <path id="mypath" fill="url(#ct-svg-gradient)" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M116.48,288.71a582.68,582.68,0,0,0-69.84-40.32q-36.32-17.74-33.52-58.06a582.72,582.72,0,0,0,0-80.65Q10.32,69.35,46.64,51.61a582.68,582.68,0,0,0,69.84-40.32q33.52-22.58,67,0a582.67,582.67,0,0,0,69.84,40.32q36.32,17.74,33.52,58.06a582.65,582.65,0,0,0,0,80.65q2.79,40.32-33.52,58.06a582.67,582.67,0,0,0-69.84,40.32Q150,311.29,116.48,288.71Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: In fact, I'm not worried only by circles, but objects I'm concerned about can be rotated without problems.

Comment: It is very difficult for you to show a way to fill the object from edge to edge when it is not quite regular?

Comment: Are you planning on animating the gradient rotation?

Comment: Nope. Just gradient angle is configured before loading the page.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example that uses JS to update the gradient.

Comment: Great one! Here's a fiddle where you can play with this function a bit easily. It works correctly, thank you!

Comment: After a long search this is the only answer that also works for non-rectangular sized paths!